# What can I say about the following matrices?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, modules

I have to examine the row and column modules of following matrices

\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6\\
7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{bmatrix}
over $\mathbb{Z_{14}}$ and
\begin{bmatrix} 
x & x^2 & 0 \\
3x & -x & x^3\\
0 & x & -x \\
\end{bmatrix}
over $\mathbb{C[x]}$.
Then I have to say if they are isomorphic, free modules and if they have an inverse.

I would need some guidance with how can I start and what could I do. My main problem in this type of excercises is that I don't fully "get" what difference does the ring over which we consider these matrices make, I get that the elements of the matrix might be from this ring but I don't grasp what this changes for me.

Would be really thankful for some help

Comment: Define row/column module for a matrix.

Comment: I think the row module is the module made of the vectors that form the rows of the matrix and the column module is the one made for the vectors used as coulumns.